# Substract one word from the other

Tags: python

I have two words:

```
word1 = sunday
word2 = sun
```

Now I would like to get this result:

```
result = word1-word2 = day
```

How can a I do it ?
I did not find anything...

Comment: The answer would depend on what would you want to see for different examples. Eg what should be result on word1 being 'daysun', 'sunsun', ''we think of more suns in winter because there is less sun' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do in general.

1) You can decide to remove **every occurence** of `word2` in `word1` by using `word1.replace(word2, "")`

2) You might also want to replace **only the first occurence**, you can do that by calling `word1.replace(word2, "", 1)`. Although, this will remove the occurence of `word2` wherever it is in `word1`.

3) Also if what you want to do is remove `word2` **only if it is at the start** of `word1`, I would go for something like this:

```
def sub(word1, word2):
    if word1[:len(word2)] == word2:
        return word1[len(word2):]
    else:
        return word1
```

Note that this assumes `word2` is shorter, you might want to add some check.

4) Finally you might want to **substract only the matching prefix** between `word1` and `word2`, by example `sunday - sunflower = day`. Which you could do by doing:

```
def sub(word1, word2):
    for index, letter in enumerate(word1):
        if letter != word2[index]:
            break
        return word1[index:]
```

Note that this again assumes `word2` is shorter.

Once you decide what the specifications of your substraction is, you can choose which solution you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) function

```
word1 = "sunday"
word2 = "sun"

word3 = word1.replace(word2, "")

print(word3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string `slicing`. We want to take the "slice" from the end of the word to be subtracted onwards. As the `index` method gives the index of the start of the string, we need to add onto this the length of the string to be subtracted to get the index of where the slice should stat from.

So, using that logic, here is a general purpose function:

```
def sub(s1, s2):
    return s1[s1.index(s2)+len(s2):]
```

and a test:

```
>>> sub("sunday", "sun")
'day'
```

Answer (score 0):

For true "subtraction", you may want to create your own string objects:

```
import re
class String:
   def __init__(self, val):
       self.s = str(val)
   def __sub__(self, value):
        return re.sub(value.s, '', self.s)

s = String('sunday')
s1 = String('sun')
print(s-s1)
```

Output:

```
day
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you're after, or whether one of these approaches might work, but you can do:

```
>>> word1 = 'sunday'
>>> word1.replace("sun", "")
'day'

# or

>>> word1[3:]
'day'
```

But no, you can't do generic substraction on strings like that.

Answer (score -1):

Python's built in string class doesn't support subtraction. Instead, you can hack your own string subtraction function by splitting string a using string b as a parameter.

This question has already been elegantly answered by [Zaka Elab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317817/zaka-elab). So, I will just share his solution:

```
def subtract(a, b):                              
  return "".join(a.rsplit(b))

subtract("sunday", "sun")
```